# How do I stop IntelliJ from starting in full-screen mode

Tags: intellij-idea

Since a recent version upgrade, Intelli/J now starts in full-screen mode. This is fine on OS-X, because the menu auto-appears. But it's rubbish on Ubuntu because the menus are hidden and do not auto-appear.

I can manually drop out of full-screen (ctrl-shift-A then type 'full' then change the option), but it's annoying to have to do this every time I start Intelli/J.

How can I change the startup settings so that full-screen is not enabled by default?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Close all Idea instances
2. Open `<project_dir>/.idea/workspace.xml`
3. Make sure there is a tag preventing fullscreen:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    ...
    <component name="PropertiesComponent">
        ...
        <property name="FullScreen" value="false" />
    </component>
</project>
```

4. Save `workspace.xml` and start Idea again.

Example: https://github.com/angular/atscript-playground/blob/5b2e8a588b28fd906f05d7748a764498b7b2e404/.idea/workspace.xml#L245

Comment: intellij doesn't seem to pay any attention to this on startup for me, though it does overwrite it on exit; it changes the value to `true` if i don't turn off fullscreen mode before exiting, and if i do turn it off it just removes the property tag altogether. this suggests to me there's some 'default' setting somewhere that's taking precedence, but i can't seem to find it.

Comment: its really annoying that this is not solved until now. i also have to exit the fullscreen *every time* i start the ide - the xml change does not take any effect :-(

Comment: I had to add the value to `keyToString` as a JSON in HTML:  `&quot;FullScreen&quot;: &quot;false&quot;`

Answer (score 2):

Since the above answers did not work for me here is the solution that finally worked for me on Pycharm / PycharmPro which is the Python adaption of IntelliJ:

1. For simplification while testing: Within IntelliJ / Pycharm: close all projects but one
2. Close all IntelliJ instances
3. Open <project_dir>/.idea/workspace.xml
4. Search for "PropertiesComponent"
5. Add the following code in a new line below:

```xml
&quot;FullScreen&quot;: &quot;false&quot;,
```

It would look like this:

```xml
...
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">{
  &quot;keyToString&quot;: {
    &quot;FullScreen&quot;: &quot;false&quot;,
...
```

6. Save and close
7. Open Pycharm and see if it worked
8. Repeat it for the other projects

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in a version of InteliJ Idea which is much more recent then the original question. If you came across this question with an early 2023 version, just install the latest upgrades to stop your IDE from always starting in full screen mode.

[image: Click here to upgrade]

See e.g.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000747570-IDEA-always-starts-in-full-screen-mode

Answer (score 1):

Edit file .idea/workspace.xml and look for property FullScreen. Change the value of this to "false".

One thing to note is that Idea seems to save the workspace.xml while when you close the the IDE. So if you edit the file while Idea is running, it might overwrite your changes. So edit the file when the project is not open in the ide.

Comment: Hey, this is September 2016 now and I don't see any workspace.xml file; does it still exist under the current IntelliJ IDEA project system? And do you mean the .idea folder in the project directory, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to switch off fullscreen at startup by editing the IDEA project file *projectname*.iws.

Search for the property with name="FullScreen" and change the value "true" to "false".

I don't know if there is any kind of "official" way to achieve that...